# Is it possible to retrieve schedule and activities data from APS?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

is it possible to retrieve schedule and activities data stored in a ACC's project (Autodesk Build) with APS API?

[Autodesk Build - Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrgCz.png)

Otherwise are there in roadmap?

TIA
Alder

I tried to check in APS but I haven't found anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, APS ACC API doesn't currently provide ACC Schedule API. However, there is an indirect way to get schedule data via Data Connector API,  which is a workaround as always when we don't have direct API support.

Here is an example call of Data Connector API for schedule data:

```bash
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data-connector/v1/accounts/7d3f0151-d90a-4193-a18d-eee02321a031/requests' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer .....' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "description": "My Schedule Data Extract",
        "isActive": true,
        "scheduleInterval": "ONE_TIME",
        "reoccuringInterval": null,
        "effectiveFrom": "2020-11-06T19:09:40.106Z",
        "effectiveTo": "2020-11-12T19:09:40.106Z",
        "serviceGroups": "[\"schedule\"]",
        "callbackUrl": "https://api.mycompany.com/autodesk/jobinfo",
        "sendEmail": true,
        "projectId": "ffffffff-1f51-4b26-a6b7-6ac0639cb138"
      }'
```

ref:

- https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/data-connector/dc-tutorial-submit-data-request/
- https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/data-connector-requests-POST/